# how to retrieve data MySQL value using python

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, python-3.x, udp

I tried to receive value from a UDP socket and send it to MySQL database and put this in sensors table . Then I tried the retrieve data from action table in MySQL data base and send it back via a UDP socket .I'm using python 3.5.

This is my Python code.

```
from random import *
import sys
import pymysql
#from datetime import datetime
from socket import *
import time

UDP_IP="192.168.1.26"
UDP_PORT = 6009
UDP_PORT2 = 5016

address= ('192.168.1.207' , 5454)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.settimeout(1)
sock = socket (AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP , UDP_PORT))
sock2 = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
sock2.bind((UDP_IP , UDP_PORT2))

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='', db='iot',port=3306)
x = conn.cursor()
try:
         x.execute("""INSERT INTO sensors VALUES (%s,%s)""",(0,0))
         conn.commit()
except:
        conn.rollback()

while True :

    data1 = "Temperature"

    client_socket.sendto(data1.encode("UTF-8") , address)

    rec_data1,addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)

    temperature = float(rec_data1)

    print (temperature)

    data2 = "humidity"

    client_socket.sendto(data2.encode("UTF-8") , address)

    rec_data2 , addr =sock2.recvfrom(2048)

    humidity = float(rec_data2)

    print (humidity)

    x.execute("""TRUNCATE TABLE `sensors`;""")
    x.execute("""INSERT INTO sensors VALUES (%s,%s)""",(temperature,humidity))
    conn.commit()
    time.sleep(1)

    x.execute("""Select tempout from action; """)
    data3 = x.fetchall()
    print(data3)
    x.execute("""Select humout from action;""")
    data4 = x.fetchall()
    print (data4)

    client_socket.sendto(data3.encode("UTF-8"), address)
    client_socket.sendto(data4.encode("UTF-8") , address)
```

This is the error that I got :

> 25.12
>   240.0 (('ON_1',),) (('OFF_2',),) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ghina\Desktop\Mysql+socketUDP.py", line 62, in 
>       client_socket.sendto(data3.encode(), address) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: i'm not familiar with `pymsql` but `data3` is obviously a tuple...you'd want to encode the string. So inspect the content of data3 it should contain the text you want to encode....you might have something like `data3[0].encode("UTF-8", address)` assuming the text is the first element in the tuple